# How to get out of a UIStoryboard initialized in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a main container controller that initializes child view controllers.

I'm trying to learn to use UIStoryboards tho and I'm stumped as to how to get out of a storyboard.

Here's the flow:

[image]

Once I get to the end of a storyboard's scenes, how should I get out of storyboard and back to my container controller?

Should I keep a pointer to the storyboard? What would I do with it?

Should I keep a pointer to the initial view controller (which is the one I explicitly add as child)? It's .view won't be on screen at the end so I don't know what I would do with that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looping through the childViewControllers

```
for (UIViewController *vc in self.childViewControllers) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "out of a storyboard". You don't need to save a pointer to your storyboard as  self.storyboard should work in most cases. If you use a UINavigationController as your entry point in your storyboard with your initial view controller as it's root view, all you have to do to get back to your initial controller is

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Also, you can get a reference to your storyboard like this as well:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: That won't work. The app isn't built around a navigation controller. And the container controller is not 'in' the storyboard. So it has no .storyboard property.

Comment: Add a navigation controller and you can get your storyboard with the "storyboardWithName" method mentioned above.